# clicking on overlay element triggers click of underlay element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I have an image with an overlay of a trash can in the top right corner. I have two click events, one when the user clicks the trash 'i.removeEvent' and the second when the user clicks the image 'div.spaceEvent', they both do different things when clicked. But when the user clicks the trash it also triggers a click event on the image. How can I stop the triggering of the image click when the trash is clicked?

Here is my code.

```js
$("div.spaceEvent").off('click').on('click', function() {
  scope.eventId = $(this).data('event-id');
  //$("#registeredMemberContainer").html('');
  scope.GetRegisteredMembersAsHost();
});


$("i.removeEvent").off('click').on('click', function() {
  scope.eventId = $(this).data('event-id');
  scope.spaceId = $(this).data('space-id');

  var model = {};
  model.eventId = scope.eventId;
  model.spaceId = scope.spaceId;
  // do other stuff here
});
```

```html
<ul class="thumbnails" style="padding-left: 0px;">
  @{ var listItems = count > 3 ? 3 : count; } @for (int j = 0; j
  < listItems; j++) { var spaceEvent=M odel.YogaSpaceEvents.ElementAt(incrament++); <li class="col-sm-4" style="padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px;">
    <div class="spaceEvent" data-event-id=@spaceEvent.YogaSpaceEventId>
      <div class="thumbnail">

        <div>
          <img class="img-responsive" style="position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;" src="data:image/jpg;base64, @(Html.Raw(Convert.ToBase64String(spaceEvent.SpaceThumbnail43)))" alt="space image">
          <i style="z-index: 200; position: absolute; top: 8px; right: 15px; color: whitesmoke;" class="fa fa-trash-o fa-2x removeEvent" data-event-id=@spaceEvent.YogaSpaceEventId data-space-id=@spaceEvent.YogaSpaceRefId data-container="body" data-toggle="popover"
            data-trigger="hover" data-placement="top" data-content="Cancel event"></i>
        </div>

        <div class="caption" style="padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px;">
          <h4 style="margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px;">@spaceEvent.Title</h4>
          <p style="margin-bottom: 0px;"><span>@spaceEvent.EventDateTime.ToShortTimeString()</span><span> &middot; </span><span>@YogaBandy2017.Models.General.EnumHelper.GetDisplayName(spaceEvent.Duration)</span></p>
          <p style="margin-bottom: 0px;">@spaceEvent.StyleMain.ToString()</p>
          <p class="teacher-container" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">Teacher: @(spaceEvent.IsTeacherRegistered ? spaceEvent.RegisteredTeacherName : "none")</p>
          <p><span class="registered-container">Registered</span>: <span class="badge">@spaceEvent.RegisteredStudentCount/@spaceEvent.MaxSize</span></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </li>
    count -= 1; }
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be invoking [stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) first thing in the click handler.

```js
$("i.removeEvent").off('click').on('click', function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  // do other stuff here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is the wanted and expected result. It's called event propagation or bubbeling.

You can avoid this by calling `event.stopPropagation()` inside the eventhandler:

```
$("i.removeEvent").off('click').on('click', function(evt) {
  evt.stopPropagation(); // this avoids the event bubbeling / propagation
  scope.eventId = $(this).data('event-id');
  scope.spaceId = $(this).data('space-id');

  var model = {};
  model.eventId = scope.eventId;
  model.spaceId = scope.spaceId;
  // do other stuff here
});
```

---

In addition of the comment: *What is the difference between event.stopPropagtion() and event.stopImmediatePropagation()?*

The difference is the following:

```
<body>
  <div>Some div Content
    <i>Close</i>
  </div>
</body>
<script>
$('div').on('click', function() {
  console.log('div was clicked!');
});
$('i').on('click', function(evt) {
  console.log('i was clicked! This message is from the first event handler!');

  // one case
  evt.stopPropagation();
  /* Message in console:
i was clicked! This message is from the first event handler!
i was clicked! This message is from the second event handler!
  */
  // other case:
  evt.stopImmediatePropagation();
  /* Message in console:
i was clicked! This message is from the first event handler!
  */

  // "div was clicked!" will never read when i is clicked. It's only displayed if the div is clicked directly.
});
$('i').on('click', function() {
  console.log('i was clicked! This message is from the second event handler!');
});
</script>
```

Comment: what's the difference between stoppropagation and stopimmediatepropagation?

Comment: if you have added more than one event handler to the event they all will executed with `event.stopPropagation()`, but with `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` it will stop the processing after the actual event handler. (I will add an example. gimme a second)

Comment: that's ok, I got it!

Comment: @user1186050 ah too late. anyway. If you have any further questions: feel free to ask :)

Comment: @user1186050 please don't forget to select your answer to the question. It's important at SO, so it's clear for all that the question is answered and you're happy ;)